# What books properly address the properties of $a^b$?

Tags: reference-request, algebra, exponent

Many students think

$\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a\ b}$

$\sqrt{a^2}=a$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}$

**but none of the above are true when (a) and (b) are negative.**

To avoid such problems, students need to learn the properties below are true for any (a, b, c) that  meet the conditions specified.

$\ a^b a^c = a^{b+c}$ when both sides are defined.

---

$a^c b^c=(a\ b)^c$ when c is an integer and both sides are defined.
$a^c b^c=(a\ b)^c$ when (0 < a < $\infty$) or (0 < b < $\infty$).

---

$\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{b\ c}$ when c is an integer and both sides are defined.
$\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{b\ c}$ when (0 < a < $\infty$).
$\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{b\ c}$ when (-1 < b $\leq$ 1).

---

$a^c b^{-c}=\frac{a^c}{b^c}$ for all$\ $ a, b, c.

$a^c b^{-c}=\frac{a^c}{b^c}=a^c \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^c=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^c$  when $c$ is an integer.

$a^c b^{-c}=\frac{a^c}{b^c}=a^c \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^c=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^c$  when (0 < b < $\infty$).

---

The caveat "when both sides are defined", excludes couter examples such as
$\ 0^5\ 0^{-2} \neq 0^{5-2}$ and $\left(0^{-2}\right)^{-3}\neq0^6.$
What books include most of the above properties?

-----**Edit**------
Actually, I only expect people to learn how some of the above identities extend to complex numbers when they are in certain fields of study. The above properties actually apply when the variables are complex numbers. An electrical engineering student should learn most of that before they study Discrete Fourier Transforms, or Z-Transforms. Sadly, some books actually tell you the fallacies above are true. One example is the following from: Ron Larson et al, Algebra II, Maryland Edition, McDougal Little, 2008.
[image: Ron Larson, et al]
Consider the next example from Daniel Zwillinger, CRC Standard Mathematical Tables and Formulae, CRC Press 1996.
[image: CRC Press]
The second example is a math reference for engineers and scientists. It covers elliptical integrals and partial differential equations, but nothing is mentioned about the properties of $a^b$ that leads to complex numbers. Many books only mention how the properties work for integer and rational exponents. What do the authors think people will do when working with approximate exponents having 16 digits of precision? Do they think people will convert the approximate exponents to rational numbers and work the problem from there? Hopefully by the time students take Pre-Calculus they lean that that the properties work in the case of a positive number to a real power.

For those in math intensive fields, the subject should be revisited by the third year at a university. I don't remember what my professors mentioned about the properties of $a^b$, but I can't find a book that covers what I am looking for. I once took a course on functions of complex variables and the text book said nothing about the properties of $a^b$.

Comment: Who are the target audience for the books you are looking for?  High school students?  Undergraduates?

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noches, The target audience would include the better high school students. Also those in the first two years at a university and are taking a lot of math courses.

Comment: Are you literally asking for book titles, or the general description of the math course?

Comment: I am not sure that I agree with your assertion that every student *needs* to know when these properties can be extended to the complex numbers, since I am not entirely sure that I agree that every student needs to know much of anything about complex numbers.  I think that the more important thing to do in this case is to very carefully emphasize the *hypotheses* of the theorem(s) at play here.  For example, for any **positive** $a$ and $b$, we have $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$.  Emphasize the necessity of positivity by watching what goes wrong with $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: Pretty much every intermediate algebra, college algebra, and precalculus text I've ever taught out of (going back to 1983) gives the appropriate restrictions for these properties to hold. Also, most books I've taught from explicitly state that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|.$ I could provide you with titles of dozens of such books on my bookshelves (not all of which I've taught from), with specific page references, but I don't see the point, because you could browse the shelves of any college/university library and find the same. Perhaps of more interest might be which texts DON'T do this.

Comment: Maybe the only books that correctly discuss $a^b$ (in your sense) are textbooks in complex analysis.

Comment: People disagree about some of those properties (most notably: along the real vs. complex analyst axis). Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628759/what-are-the-laws-of-rational-exponents

Comment: In your CRC example, we are to assume *all quantities* are real. For example, with $\sqrt[x]{ab}=\sqrt[x]{a}\sqrt[x]{b}$ we must assume the quantities $\sqrt[x]{a}$ and $\sqrt[x]{b}$ are real. So the text is not incorrect.

Comment: @user52817 has pointed out that the CRC case doesn't appear to qualify as an error, and it seems pretty evident to me that the Larson, et al. case is an editing oversight (because all the examples involve positive bases; if this assumption is stated on the p. 330 cited, then it's definitely an editing oversight).

Comment: Note that there are multiple answers in the thread I linked above that argue a clause like "all quantities are defined [real]" is insufficient to make these properties well-defined.